# Magento Product URL (rewrite)

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls

I created a new product under category `domain.com/product/alpha`, and when I open `domain.com/product/alpha` I can see the product, however when I click the product instead of opening the URL as `domain.com/product/alpha/sampleProduct` it opens as `domain.com/sampleProduct`.

I googled and found that I need to rewrite the URL in Marketing, but if it's the solution, isn't it odd? shouldn't the product be created under the category because I added it under that category?

Now if I have 200 products, editing each product is gonna take time. Please tell me whats the solution here, or if I did something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I added a custom url under search engine optimization, but the new url now becomes `domain.com/product/alpha/product/alpha/sampleProduct` rather than `domain.com/product/alpha/sampleProduct`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a bit of explanation on product category association.

Products and Categories are two different entities. They are associated to each other by Many-to-Many Rule which means one product could be in multiple categories & similarly one category can have multiple different products.

Each Category has its own URL where you can see its landing page, information & list of all products those belongs to that specific category. I assume `domain.com/product/alpha` is your category view URL. In this you will see all the products those are associated with this `alpha` category, if you associate more than one products.

Similarly, each Product has its own URL which shows the detailed page of that specific product. In this URL you see all information about this specific product. That is the reason when you click on product from category view it gets redirected to product view.

> shouldn't the product be created under the category because I added it
> under that category

No, since the same product can be associated with multiple categories then it would have been ambigious to get url like `domain.com/product/alpha/product`

Hope it was helpful.
Thanks

Comment: a product page such as `domain.com/product` is not friendly, i don't want such URL, perhaps a product page as `domain.com/product/sub-catgeory/PRODUCT-NAME` is more friendly. this is what I want to achieve for all the products.